# Gradle allprojects in React-native

Tags: android, react-native

I know a thing or two about JS and react-native. I was trying to comprehend the JAVA config of RN (by going through the Android docs in google developer training)

[In this Section](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-1-get-started/lesson-1-build-your-first-app/1-1-c-your-first-android-app/1-1-c-your-first-android-app.html#buildgradle-project-apptitle), The author have written following line

> If a dependency is something other than a local library or file tree, Gradle looks for the files in whichever online repositories are specified in the repositories block of this file

I am Unable to comprhend the above line.

Also, In my current react-native project, it looks something like this (build.gradle)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Where as in project created by android it looks like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Can someone explain the difference? what is

```
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

And

```
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
```

Why does RN people have them like this when compared to Android project created by android studio